# Do varchars in SQLServer preserve their encoding?

Tags: c#, sql-server

If I persist a windows-1252 string (e.g. something with "smart quotes") from C# to a record into a SQLServer db, is the encoding preserved if I read it back out into another string variable?

Comment: It'll depend on the encoding in the server I think.

Comment: a server has a particular encoding?

Comment: Some implementations (e.g. MySQL) ignore NVARCHAR and instead opt to define an encoding on all VARCHAR columns. Whether that's sane, useful or better than the usual way of handling this I don't know. People should just use Unicode and be done with any legacy encodings if possible, I think.

Comment: @Joey Thanks for the info. I agree we should be done with codepages. I still have to deal with smart quotes, which I dont think UTF8 allows. Does it?

Comment: UTF-8 is a transformation format of the Universal character set (aka Unicode). It supports all characters used in all legacy encodings to date (except maybe some private use things). That's actually been a core requirement of Unicode that it allows 1-to-1 mappings of all existing character sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, no or maybe.

Each VARCHAR column in SQL Server has a "collation", roughly equivalent to a codepage (character set) plus a sort order.

If the codepage of the collation can store all the characters in the string they should round-trip properly. If not, not.

If your collation is a variant of `Latin1_General` you should be able to store the whole windows-1252 character set.

For more, see here:

- Windows Collation Name:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046.aspx
- Collation and International Terminology: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx
- Char and Varchar: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Note that if you haven't set a collation on the field, it will use the database's default collation, which is usually `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

It is important to be aware of character set issues. If you need to store characters in one field which cannot all be fitted into the same codepage you need to use NVARCHAR. In an NVARCHAR field, all characters can be stored and the collation only controls the sort order and equality comparisions.

Comment: And you shouldn't change the database's "default" collation.

Comment: @aF, Not once it is set, no. If you really want to change the collation do it column by column -- after you have rewritten all your queries to use explicit collations!

Comment: @aF. I didnt know you could do that.

Comment: @Ben, yep. If we have all database data with a collation and then change that collation it can give some problems. ^^

Comment: @fullNelson sometimes is better not to know :P But basically should be used when you don't have any data on database but don't need to drop it and create it again with another collation.